Tracing back to original graph of a line graph.
The line graph of an undirected graph $G$ is another graph $L(G)$ that represents the adjacencies between edges of $G$. $L(G)$ is constructed in the following way: for each edge in $G$, make a vertex in $L(G)$; for every two edges in $G$ that have a vertex in common, make an edge between their corresponding vertices in $L(G)$. Further, there is a 9 graph forbidden characterization due to Beineke. My question is suppose we are given a graph $L(G)$ such that it does not contain any of the Beineke's 9 graphs as an induced subgraph, then can we trace back to the graph $G$? Is $G$ unique in such a case?

There's only one case where the graph is not unique in fact, assuming connectivity.

There is a small counterexample: $L(K_3) = L(K_{1,3}) = K_3$.
However, this is essentially it: two connected graphs that are not $K_3$ and $K_{1,3}$ only have isomorphic line graphs if they are themselves isomorphic. (For graphs that are not connected, you could have a $K_3$ component and replace it by a $K_{1,3}$ component with no change to the line graph.)

Here is how to prove this, and also how to go from a line graph $G$ to a graph $H$ such that $G = L(H)$. I will assume $G$ is connected; otherwise, solve the problem on each component.
For each vertex of $H$ with degree $2$ or more, the edges out of $H$ form a clique in $G$. These cliques are edge-disjoint, cover all edges of $G$, and cover each vertex of $G$ at most twice. (Some vertices of $G$ are covered only once or not at all, if they come from an edge of $H$ with a degree-$1$ endpoint.)
Conversely, by a theorem of Krausz, if we can cover $G$ with cliques in this way (each edge covered exactly once, each vertex at most twice), then $G$ is a line graph, and the cliques correspond to vertices of an $H$ such that $G = L(H)$ (so we learn what $H$ is). This clique decomposition is called a Krausz decomposition of $G$.
There are several cases that make it easy to find the Krausz decomposition.

If $G$ has no triangles, then $H$ must have maximum degree $1$ or $2$ (it's a path or cycle), so $G = L(H)$ is either a path that's one edge shorter, or a cycle of the same length. The Krausz decomposition is just the set of edges.
If $G$ has a maximal clique with $4$ or more vertices, that clique must be part of the Krausz decomposition. (There's no way to cover that clique with smaller edge-disjoint cliques without covering a vertex $3$ times.)
One more case (described later) will give us a triangle that must be part of the Krausz decomposition.
Once we pick one clique for the Krausz decomposition, there is a unique way to finish it: if a vertex was already used in one clique, and has more edges left to cover, then all those edges must be part of another clique, which tells us what that clique has to be. (Repeat this until all edges are covered.)

It remains to worry about $G = L(H)$ when $H$ has maximum degree exactly $3$.
Let $u$ be a vertex of $H$ with neighbors $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and suppose that one of the neighbors (without loss of generality, $v_1$) is adjacent to some fifth vertex $w$. Then in $G$, the edges $uv_1, uv_2, uv_3$ form a triangle, and edge $v_1w$ is adjacent to only vertex $uv_1$ in that triangle. Call this configuration (a triangle in $G$, with a vertex outside it adjacent to only one vertex of the triangle) an odd triangle. Note that these odd triangles are guaranteed to appear in $L(H)$ when the maximum degree is $3$, unless $H$ has no vertices other than $u, v_1, v_2, v_3$.
When there are no $4$-cliques, odd triangles are also uniquely determined picks for the Krausz decomposition! If we have a triangle $\{x,y,z\}$ in $G$ with $x'$ adjacent to $x$ but not to $y,z$, then edges $xy$, $xz$, $xx'$ must be covered by at most two cliques, which means $xy$ and $xz$ must be covered by the same clique.
So the only remaining cases to solve are when $G$ contains no cliques of size $4$, and no odd triangles. We might try assuming $H$ has maximum degree $1$ or $2$ (it's a path or cycle), and then we know what $H$ is. Except for the case $H = K_3$, $G = L(H)$ has no triangles at all in this case, so our assumption is justified... when $G = K_3$, things are still left ambiguous.
The other option is to assume that $H$ has maximum degree $3$, in which case (because $G$ has no odd triangles) $H$ has only $4$ vertices. This gives us four cases:

$H = K_{1,3}$, which is the second solution to $G = K_3$.
$H$ is a triangle with a leaf added, and $G = K_4 - e$.
$H = K_4 - e$, and $G$ is a wheel graph: a $4$-cycle with a degree-$4$ vertex added.
$H = K_4$, and $G$ is the octahedral graph.

Except for $G = K_3$, all of these have unambiguous preimages $H$ up to isomorphism. They do, however, give us three more cases where the Krausz decomposition is not unique. (This means we cannot be certain which triangles in $G$ come from degree-$3$ vertices in $H$.)
